# Are there built-in extension methods in the .NET framework that don't apply to LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

For the purpose of a course I am developing, I am looking for some examples of where Microsoft has already implemented extension methods themselves. But since the students are not yet acquainted to LINQ, I would like to find some other example.

So, are there any methods defined in the .NET framework that are defined as an extension method, but do not refer to the LINQ framework or IEnumerable?

Comment: DataTableExtensions Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions

Comment: [Files named ExensionMethods.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=extensionmethods.cs) in the framework source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.net uses them in `GetCustomAttributes<T>`for example.
See [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs,107).

Comment: Good example, I might use it, although I haven't touched on reflection yet with them. I will add some more information to the question about the level the students are at.

Comment: Also, one [ListExtension](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Extension) method

Comment: @Marnix they are relatively rare since they were introduced not so long ago, when most of the frameworks code allready existed.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will accept this answer for now and see how I will deal with it in my course. Thanks for thinking along.

Comment: @CSharpie 2007 is not that long ago to you?  Over 11 years is decency long in the field.  The feature has been in the language for more than twice as long as it has been without it.

Comment: @Servy You are righgt .net 3.5 introdocued them. Thought they came way later.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few actually. I downloaded the .Net Framework source code for version 4.8 (May 2019 upgrade). To do so yourself just click Download in the [reference source website](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Unzip the file then open the solution with Visual Studio and search for (using regular expressions) :

> Class .*Extensions

It returned 61 hits to me, I'm sure you will be able to find proper examples for your course. I suppose the best one would be `DoubleExtensions` ([see here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/cdf/src/NetFx40/Tools/System.Activities.Presentation/System/Activities/Presentation/FreeFormEditing/DoubleExtensions.cs,688ab031253eee0f)) as it is an easy one to understand.

Comment: Oh that's nice! I like this one. Thanks.

Comment: So, which library should I import in my project to get this in? The reference source website states it should be in System.Data and System.Activities.Presentation, but the FreeformEditing namespace doesn't seem to be in those libraries. How does the reference website show which library I need?

Comment: It seems that DoubleExtensions is actually part of the netfx framework, which can be downloaded from nuget.

Comment: @Marnix System.Activities.Presentation project in the source code. But I would make a small project a copy/paste the code not to be bothered with other details and dependencies

Comment: @Marnix That's an `internal` class you're looking at, professor...were you expecting to use it for something, or just show the source code as an example?

Comment: I was hoping to let them make an exercise with that. Didn't notice the internal keyword. Thanks for the notion.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing coursework, perhaps the [ZipFileExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions?view=netframework-4.8) are a good API. People tend to be able to wrap their heads around .zip files, and these APIs are generally pretty easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there are tons of examples here are some highlights:

1. AsSpan() method on string that is implemented as an extension method. [Here are the docs on it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=netstandard-2.1#System_MemoryExtensions_AsSpan_System_String_)
2. IsNormalized() and Normailize() are two more string extension methods that are easy enough to use. [Here are the docs on those.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringnormalizationextensions?view=netcore-3.0)
3. If you are willing to walk your students into Dependency Injection then there are plenty of examples in the Startup class for just about any asp.net core project.

Comment: *"are there any methods defined in the .NET framework ..."*

Comment: I want to show them that .NET uses it themselves as well and that it might be that you see a function that is part of, let's say, a string, but you cannot find it back in `System`. Sometimes you have to look further and find the right library. Just as when you forget to type `using System.Linq`

Comment: Updated it to include an example. Sorry about that

Comment: @rahicks but you are defining the extension method yourself. OP is asking for methods which are already defined within the .NET Framework.